# DropDownList inaccessible

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down list in my TopicTreeSearchControl, on my page, but from the actually page where the control sits, I get an error:

```
'TopicSearchTree.ddlDatasources' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

I am trying to do this from my page:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(TopicSearchTreeControl.ddlDatasources.UniqueID);
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(TopicSearchTreeControl.ddlYears.UniqueID);
    base.Render(writer);
}
```

How do I access this?

Answer (score 1):

Place a property inside the control which exposes the data source

```
internal DataSource DropDownListDataSource
{
    get { return ddlDataSources; }
}
```

Although this seems like a bigger architecture problem. You should register it for validation inside the control.